# CIImage memory leak in AVVideoCompositing

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avkit

I'm using [Cabbage](https://github.com/VideoFlint/Cabbage) for overlaying and images on top of the video. But I run into an issue, when I have a memory leak in **CIImage** never released from the memory, even when **ViewController** which started exportSession is deinited.
I use a standard initiation, like they framework has in the demo app:

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ProductOnly_Female_Tops_1_custom", withExtension: "jpg")!
    let image = CIImage(contentsOf: url)!
```

Code for startRequest method of **AVVideoCompositing** :

```
open func startRequest(_ request: AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest) {
    renderingQueue.async(execute: { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        if strongSelf.shouldCancelAllRequests {
            request.finishCancelledRequest()
        } else {
            autoreleasepool {
                if let resultPixels = strongSelf.newRenderedPixelBufferForRequest(request: request) {
                    request.finish(withComposedVideoFrame: resultPixels)
                } else {
                    request.finish(with: PixelBufferRequestError.newRenderedPixelBufferForRequestFailure)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can get rid of this leak?

You may find demo project [here](https://github.com/VideoFlint/Cabbage/issues/71#issuecomment-833892406)

Screenshot of memory allocation:
[image]

Comment: Never used Cabbage but is it possible to create your instance from the bundle to Data and from there convert, maybe the allocation can't release because is always pointing to the Bundle and can't let go. Just a question.

Comment: @WilsonMuñoz the problem persist, even if I pass an empty CIImage()

Comment: Did you solve it?
I'm currently facing this memory leak problem.